# PHP executes its script and then closes its window

Tags: php, windows, cmd, executable

I have configured Windows 7 so that .php files run as executable.

```
assoc .php=phpfile
ftype phpfile="C:\PHP5\php.exe" -f "%1" -- %~2
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

Now, when I double click on a .php file it executes and then the cmd window is closed. I don't see anything. How I can make it wait.

How can I make it so that the window will not close?

Answer (score 1):

Add [`fgetc(STDIN)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetc.php) to the end of the script.

This should cause the app to wait for input. All you'd need to do is hit enter to close the window.

Or, if you'd like it to wait a second and then close, use [`sleep(n)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)